# Data integrity when using parallel stream

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-stream

I have the implemented the below and I have not tested it yet with large amount of data.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData();
        List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList("x1", "x3", "x2");
        nameList.parallelStream().forEach(name -> {
            populateDetails(name, combinedData);
        });
    }

    static void log(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    static void populateDetails(String name, CombinedData combinedData) {
        if (combinedData.getOrg() == null) {
            combinedData.setOrg(MyUtil.getOrg(name));
        }
        if (combinedData.getRawData() != null) {
            combinedData.setRawData(combinedData.getRawData() + name);
        }
        combinedData.addToDetails(new Details(name, MyUtil.getAdd(name)));
    }
}

class CombinedData {
    private String org;
    private List<Details> details;
    private String rawData;

    public String getOrg() {
        return org;
    }

    public void setOrg(String org) {
        this.org = org;
    }

    public void addToDetails(Details details) {
        this.details.add(details);
    }

    public List<Details> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<Details> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getRawData() {
        return rawData;
    }

    public void setRawData(String rawData) {
        this.rawData = rawData;
    }
}

class Details {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Details(
            String name,
            String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

If you check the line 13 and 16 I need to add the org to combined response only once and I have added the check there and also I need to append the name to the rawData. My question is that since I'm using parallel stream how would that behave.

Im sure there might be a scenario that when threads are in parallel thing might break.

How can I go ahead and handle that scenario?

Comment: *"I need to add the org to combined response only once"* If so, you probably should change condition to `if (combinedData.getOrg() == null)`, don't you think? I.e. set the value if not yet assigned. --- But how did you expect that to be a "combined" value? If the org depends on value of `name`, then there can be more than one org, right? So which org do you expect to see in combined result?

Comment: *"since I'm using parallel stream how would that behave"* Very badly. Race conditions galore. --- *"How can I go ahead and handle that scenario?"* Synchronize the methods. Or don't use parallel streams. In that code, parallel will likely be *slower* than single-threaded stream.

Comment: @andreas It was a typo ... edited it now

Comment: That’s more than a typo. In case of `getRawData()`/`setRawData` you need a meaningful action when it is `null` (to make it non-`null`), then, a *different* action when it is non-`null`. In case of `setOrg`, it seems illogical that the task needs to be done only once, but somehow depends on the current value (as `MyUtil.getOrg(name)` suggests). And why don’t you perform an action intended to be done only once right *before* the stream operation? The other concurrency related problem have been mentioned by @Andreas already.